# How to set kubernetes secret as as connection string password in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, .net-core

I have a connection string in my .NET Core application that is used to connect to a database.

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "BloggingDatabase": "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
    },
}
```

I can use plain text password in development. But in kubernetes deployment, I am creating secrets as environment variables.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  db_password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

and pod like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: my_app:v1
    env:
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: db_password
```

But my connection string is not separated the password and username. So how can I replace it in Kubernetes deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read these evironment variables in .NET Core like this:

**First way**

```
env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: Production
        - name: POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: test-secret
              key: postgres_connection_string
```

Usage:

```
var connectionString = Evironment.GetEvironmentVariable("POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING");
```

**Second way (recommended)**

1. Kubernetes deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-project
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-project
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-project-container
        image: hamidmusayev04/test_project:1.0.8
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /hc
            port: 80
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: Production
        - name: AppSettings__ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection # PATH OF YOUR VARIABLE INSIDE appsettings.json
          valueFrom: # or just set value
            secretKeyRef:
              name: test-secret
              key: postgres_connection_string
```

2. appsettings.json

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": ""
  }
}
```

3. Usage

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(”DefaultConnection”);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [k8’s official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-secret) , you need to create a config  file that holds your username and password as secret. As per your config you missed to add the username to which the password should hold.

Below is the sample configuration , change accordingly :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: bXktYXBw
  password: Mzk1MjgkdmRnN0pi
```

Refer to this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-cases) for more information and use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to create some sort of namespace for your application to bind multiple environment variables to the application with a wildcard in AddEnvironmentVariables.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: connectionstrings-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  CONN_MYSQL: base64connectionstring
  CONN_POSTGRES: base64connectionstring
```

and reference in deployment yaml as usual.

code ......

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string MYSQL { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Postgres { get; set; } = null!;
}

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables("CONN_");

builder.Services.AddOptions<ConnectionStrings>().Bind(builder.Configuration);
```

Now mysql contains the value from CONN_MYSQL and postgres from CONN_POSTGRES.